# How to handle a file being dragged onto a jar?

Tags: java, file-association

Does anyone know how to make it so that when I go to drag a file onto a jar fie it will give the

```
+Open with ...
```

option? Can this be done with Java?

[image]

Comment: Open.. & Open with etc are platform specific behavior. I do not think this can be done with Java alone.

Comment: I'll try creating a program in C++ that will just pass the file that's dragged onto its executable as an argument to the JVM :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not directly support dragging a document onto the icon of the Jar (or in this case, the shortcut), but [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) *does* provide a facility to declare interest in a file type (a file association).

To have it open in the app. double click that document type, or right click and go to 'open with'.

Note that lots of apps. add a file type association for most images, so you'll be fighting it out with them as to which is the default 'double click' behavior.  I don't like your chances of maintaining that default, given many paint apps. will check file association defaults and offer to 'grab back' any that are not assigned to itself.

See the [JNLP File Services demo.](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs) which..

> ..prompts the user to associate file extension `.zzz` (simply a file type unlikely to clash with existing file associations) of content type `text/sleepytime`. The build file allows the file-type to be set at build time, see the `build.xml` in the distributable for details.

Answer (score 0):

OK, You cannot implement drag-and-drop for a JAR file. However, you can implement drag-and-drop of files for all the `JComponents` (like `JFrame`, `JLabel`, etc) by changing transfer handlers.

Transfer handlers allow you to:
1. Specify how the component exports data (if any)
2. Specify what data it imports (in your case the image file)
3. What data is imported / exported.

Here is the tutorial to `TransferHandler`. Here is a detailed tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/transferhandler.html